# ss/config file not working but ssh works

Tags: ssh

I am trying to login to `final_host` from `localhost` via an intermediate `hop`, i.e:

```
localhost -> hop -> final_host
```

This works:

```
localhost:~$ ssh -t user@hop "ssh user@final_host"
```

This also works:

```
localhost:~$ ssh user@hop
hop:~$ ssh user@final_host
finalhost:~$
```

But this doesn't:

```
localhost:~$ ssh -J user@hop_ip "ssh user@final_host_ip" -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -l user -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' hop_ip
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l user -vvv -W '[final_host_ip]:22' hop_ip
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to hop_ip port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to hop_ip:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from hop_ip
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:c18UMgj7nokTZJHMGnbsOgxDHlIZc2r184efDHtoTLE
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from hop_ip
debug1: Host 'hop_ip' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: server_key_folder/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f953cc00d70), agent
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:IhOfM2s2i/vFgY/Mj962CoNez631HDIMDRjxFvDhOEI server_key_folder/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:IhOfM2s2i/vFgY/Mj963CoNez631HDIMDRvxFvDhOEI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:IhOfM2s2i/vFgY/Mj963CoNez631HDIMDRvxFvDhOEI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to hop_ip ([hop_ip]:22).
debug3: ssh_init_stdio_forwarding: final_host_ip:22
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd final_host_ip:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: \033]1337;PushKeyLabels=fish_%self\033]1337;SetKeyLabel=F2=GitSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4


debug1: ssh_exchange_identification:
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: \024n��3�\030d\206\206�\235A6
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: ly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: sh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 100
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: channel 0: FORCE input drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug1: stdio forwarding: done
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

It gets stuck for a while before closing the connection. Using a config file with `ProxyJump`, `ProxyCommand -W` or `ProxyCommand + nc` also doesn't work and gets stuck at the same point. Additionally this stopped working at some point, I was able to use ProxyCommand in the past and it suddenly stopped working one day without apparent config change from my side. What could be going on here and what can I do to debug further?

EDIT: I should point out that other users of the same system are able to login without issue via config file so the problem is most likely local.

Comment: What does `type -a ssh` show for you on the local system? Are you using some sort of wrapper for ssh? Can you test with a different `hop` server?

Comment: `ssh is /usr/bin/ssh`. I am not using any wrapper. Unfortunately can't test with a different hop (the hop is managed by someone else).

Comment: I would suggest checking the permissions on your ~/.ssh directory - should _not_ be world-readable, but instead be 700 (r/w/x only by owner)

Comment: @eggo, thanks. I checked my permissions and the issue persists.

Comment: The debug log contains `ssh_exchange_identification: \033]1337;PushKeyLabels` which looks like some kind of escape sequence to emit some text. Are you sure your `.bashrc` or some other config doesn't mess with your Jump host environment?

Answer (score 2):

Authentication to final_host succeeds, but you get this error: `getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor`.

The ssh daemon on the final_host and hop should connect file descriptors for you to use (stdin, stdout, stderr) on your localhost. This fails.

The function mentioned should point you in the right direction. You are using an IP address that might not have a reverse dns entry, nor a line in /etc/hosts.

Comment: thanks, can you clarify how to get to a resolution based on your answer?

Comment: Based on above answer, it can be fixed by adding mapping for `hop` and `final_host` in `hosts` file

Comment: thanks for your comment, I added `hop` and `final_host` to my local `/etc/hosts` file and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @bbaassssiiee, Where can you see that authenthification to final_host succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the fish shell on macOS. A related [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/839776) also mentioned fish and the iTerm2 shell integration, however removing and updating it made no difference for me.

In the end I discovered that I had another integration I created for auto-sourcing Python virtualenvs that was causing the problem - when I started a new shell without sourcing that the hanging did not occur.

For reference, the contents of my auto-source-venv.fish was

```
if test -e $VIRTUAL_ENV
    source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate.fish
end
```

Which seems simple enough, and I'm not sure why SSH would be setting the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable. However, as the [fish docs say](https://fishshell.com/docs/3.2/cmds/test.html), when testing the variable should be wrapped in double quotes - and indeed, after replacing the first line with `if test -e "$VIRTUAL_ENV"`, my SSH ProxyJump is no longer hanging and connects as expected.